# Uploading non-media files?

Tags: media, filesystem

I want to add files on WordPress that are non images, embedded video and the like. However when I try this using the upload media feature I get the following error.

> "File type does not meet security guidelines."

Is there a way to do this using WordPress?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways that error can be triggered ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L307) ):

- user does not have `unfiltered_upload` capability;
- WP does not like file type or extension.

Latter is checked by `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` function ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/functions.php#L2377) ) that filters return through `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` hook to allow validation of additional file types.

Comment: I am the site admin, so that is not really a problem. But how can I allow other types of media files? Is there way to disable those filter functions?

Comment: @Bryan Harrington sorry, I had not worked with uploads at all and don't have clear idea about implementing custom validation. Quick search through usual resources got me this -[allow upload of more file types](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-tip-allow-upload-of-more-file-types).

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Rarst Answer, I've tried the filter [**`wp_check_filetype_and_ext`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1868) and this is how it can be used to allow PHP file types:

```
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'file_and_ext_wpse_9289', 10, 4 );

function file_and_ext_wpse_9289( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes )
{
    if( false !== strpos( $filename, '.php' ) )
    {
        $types['ext'] = 'php';
        $types['type'] = 'text/x-php';
    }
    return $types;
}
```

However, the easiest way is using the filter `upload_mimes`:

- [White-list file types for media upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43657/12615)
- [What is the correct MIME type for PSD (Photoshop)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46125/12615)

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error when I was trying to upload `.java` source files.

Use your favorite text editor and open file `wp-includes/functions.php`.
Search for `'mpeg'`, the second occurrence will get you inside a 
function called get_allowed_mime_types.
I added `'java'` to the line that had `'txt|asc|c|cc|h'`.  Now the file
upload is working fine for `.java` files.

Comment: It's not a good idea to update core files (like those in the `wp-includes` directory).  Any future updates to WordPress may overwrite your changes.  You're far better to use the robust filter system to modify how WordPress works -- in this case, you can [add a filter to `upload_mimes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes).