# What is the correct MIME type for PSD (Photoshop)

Tags: functions

I am trying to create an upload area (frontend) for word press users on a site. I've got a lot of types opened up through some function calls, but unable to correctly get PSD support. I'm seeing a lot of different types, and to my knowledge have tried all. I'm not sure if my hosting environment makes any difference. Am on Hostgator VPS.

Anyone successfully gotten WP to upload PSDs?

Comment: My hosting MIME type area lists it as `'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'` ... skipping it for now. Hopefully people who make PSDs are smart enough to zip them...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use to allow PSD upload:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');

function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['psd'] = 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Comment: I already have this exact code actually. Not sure why it's not working. I still get this message `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons` when trying to upload through WP media uploader.

Comment: Update. Something must have been wrong. I know I had it character for character, but must have had some invalid white-space somewhere or something... I ended up copying your line (just the $existing_mimes['psd'].... part) and it worked perfectly - finally! Been beating my head against the desk on this one. Thanks for making me try again.

Answer (score 6):

A quite horrible mimetype with several values - all of which are in use:

`image/vnd.adobe.photoshop`

`application/x-photoshop`

`application/photoshop`

`application/psd`

`image/psd`

Comment: Apparently, also `image/x-photoshop`
Source: Android Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop also uses `application/x-photoshop`.  I imagine it varies from version to version.