# can not upload file .vtt on wordpress 5.0.1

Tags: uploads, security

I updated my site to wordpress 5.0.1, but now I can not upload file .vtt anymore. This function works properly on wordpress 4.9.8

[image]

Comment: check this article - https://tribulant.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-fix-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons/ Hope it will help you

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on WP 5.0.1. It's worth noting that `.vtt` files are among the [default allowed file types](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/06b2e1776c017717eb083cc4568882507bb6f013/wp-includes/functions.php#L2664) defined WP's `mime_types` filter.

Comment: This could be related to the hardening of the mime type verifications in the security update of 5.0.1

Answer (score 4):

I did some debugging and was able to reproduce and solve the issue, but unfortunately I was not able to figure out the specific cause. Generally speaking, it seems that `.vtt` files are failing the check performed by [`wp_check_filetype_and_ext()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/06b2e1776c017717eb083cc4568882507bb6f013/wp-includes/functions.php#L2481).

I was able to upload `.vtt` files (Only tested on WP 5.0.1) after creating a simple plugin containing the following code [adapted from this answer by brasofilo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95361/2807):

```
// Sets the extension and mime type for .vtt files.
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse_file_and_ext', 10, 4 );
function wpse_file_and_ext( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $filename, '.vtt' ) ) {
        $types['ext'] = 'vtt';
        $types['type'] = 'text/vtt';
    }

    return $types;
}
```

I also noted that [`.vtt` files are already included in the allowed mimes by default](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/06b2e1776c017717eb083cc4568882507bb6f013/wp-includes/functions.php#L2664) by WP, so it should not be (and indeed isn't) necessary to add the `vtt` mime type to the list handled by the `upload_mimes` filter. e.g.:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpse_mime_types');
function wpse_mime_types( $mimes ) {
  $mimes['vtt'] = 'text/vtt';
  return $mimes;
}
```

because the entry for `vtt` already exists.

I'm using a simple [demonstration VTT file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API) named `test.vtt` with the following contents:

> WEBVTT - This file has no cues.

Comment: awesome, it works

Answer (score 3):

When a file is uploaded, WordPress peeks into it to see what it's made of, to find out the real mime type. This is determined from this part in `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()`:

```
$finfo = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
$real_mime = finfo_file( $finfo, $file );
```

This will say that the real mime type of a `.vtt` file, is `text/plain`.

The changes in `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` in 5.0.1 made the mime type validation more strict. Now it's making sure that the real mime type of the file, described by `$real_mime`, must match the one from the file's extension from `wp_check_filetype()`, if it's supported.

The reason why the `.vtt` upload fails in 5.0.1 is that the real mime type `text/plain` is not the same as `text/vtt` from the supported `.vtt` file extension.

Before 5.0.1 the output of `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` when uploading a .vtt file:

```
Array ( [ext] => vtt [type] => text/vtt [proper_filename] => )
```

After 5.0.1 the output is:

```
Array ( [ext] => [type] => [proper_filename] => )
```

Using the `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` filter can override the logic introduced in 5.0.1 as demonstrated by Dave Romsey in the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/321815/26350).

The same seems to happen for `.csv` files, as reported here [#45615](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45615)

This should be resolved in WordPress 5.0.3 for `vtt`.

Comment: ps: I created a core ticket [#45622](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45622) for the `.vtt` case

Comment: pps: posted a workaround [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/323757/26350) to handle multiple mime fallbacks per file extension.