# How to assign multiple file-mime-types to extension?

Tags: uploads, ziparchive

To allow extra file types for upload, we use:

```
add_filter('mime_types', 'my_mimes');
function my_mimes($all)
{
    $all['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    return $all;
}
```

But how to assign multiple file types to 1 extension?
For example, `zip` extension might have `application/zip` mime and also `application/x-zip` (like, coming from `7zip`). This way doesn't work:

```
$all['zip'] = ['application/zip', 'application/x-zip'] ;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note the stricter mime type check since WP 5.0.1 where the file content and file extension must match. See e.g. this recent [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/321804/26350) on the `vtt` file type.

### Secondary mime type for a given file extension

Here's a suggestion how to support a secondary mime type for a given file extension. Let's take `.vtt` as an example. The core assumes the mime type of `text/vtt` for that file extension, but the real mime type from `finfo_file()` can sometimes be `text/plain`. The `finfo_file()` seems to be somewhat [buggy](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75380). We can add a support for it as a secondary mime type with:

```
/**
 * Support for 'text/plain' as the secondary mime type of .vtt files,
 * in addition to the default 'text/vtt' support.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_secondary_mime', 99, 4 );    

function wpse323750_secondary_mime( $check, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    if ( empty( $check['ext'] ) && empty( $check['type'] ) ) {
        // Adjust to your needs!
        $secondary_mime = [ 'vtt' => 'text/plain' ];

        // Run another check, but only for our secondary mime and not on core mime types.
        remove_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_secondary_mime', 99, 4 );
        $check = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $secondary_mime );
        add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_secondary_mime', 99, 4 );
    }
    return $check;
}
```

Here we use the `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` filter to see if the check failed. In that case we run `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` again but now only on our secondary mime type, disabling our filter callback in the meanwhile to avoid an infinite loop.

### Multiple mime types for a given file extension

If we need to support more than two mime types for the `.vtt` files, then we can expand the above snippet with:

```
/**
 * Demo: Support for 'text/foo' and 'text/bar' mime types of .vtt files,
 * in addition to the default 'text/vtt' support.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_multi_mimes', 99, 4 );

function wpse323750_multi_mimes( $check, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    if ( empty( $check['ext'] ) && empty( $check['type'] ) ) {
        // Adjust to your needs!
        $multi_mimes = [ [ 'vtt' => 'text/foo' ], [ 'vtt' => 'text/bar' ] ];

        // Run new checks for our custom mime types and not on core mime types.
        foreach( $multi_mimes as $mime ) {
            remove_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_multi_mimes', 99, 4 );
            $check = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $mime );
            add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'wpse323750_multi_mimes', 99, 4 );
            if ( ! empty( $check['ext'] ) ||  ! empty( $check['type'] ) ) {
                return $check;
            }
        }
    }
    return $check;
}
```

I hope you can test it further and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: sorry, cant fully understand, is it ok to define like this  -  https://pastebin.com/raw/wRZbxqPU  ?

Comment: and what if i dont want to touch other mimes, just i am aiming only specific one. So, this is not correct way:  https://pastebin.com/raw/L86wZt3Z  and what to do?

Comment: Will have a better look when i get back online

Comment: @birgire hmm, I though this question works the other way - one extension, multiple mime types...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż thanks for the heads up, I read it the other way around, just too distracted on xmas related things these days :-)

Comment: Uff, I was starting to think that I’m loosing my mind because of that xmass stuff ;)

Comment: @T.Todua I posted a suggestion that you can hopefully work with. Since I already had the .vtt file to test I used it in the example. I hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: @T.Todua you're welcome, glad if it helped

Answer (score 3):

A little improved birgire's answer. Had to add multiple mime types for `svg`, but because `svg` is forbidden by default, had to add dynamic filter to `upload_mimes`:

```
class Multiple_Mimes {

    public static function init() {
        add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', [self::class, 'add_multiple_mime_types'], 99, 3 );
    }


    public static function add_multiple_mime_types( $check, $file, $filename ) {
        if ( empty( $check['ext'] ) && empty( $check['type'] ) ) {
            foreach ( self::get_allowed_mime_types() as $mime ) {
                remove_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', [ self::class, 'add_multiple_mime_types' ], 99 );
                $mime_filter = function($mimes) use ($mime) {
                    return array_merge($mimes, $mime);
                };

                add_filter('upload_mimes', $mime_filter, 99);
                $check = wp_check_filetype_and_ext( $file, $filename, $mime );
                remove_filter('upload_mimes', $mime_filter, 99);
                add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', [ self::class, 'add_multiple_mime_types' ], 99, 3 );
                if ( ! empty( $check['ext'] ) || ! empty( $check['type'] ) ) {
                    return $check;
                }
            }
        }

        return $check;
    }


    public static function get_allowed_mime_types(){
        return [
            [ 'svg' => 'image/svg' ],
            [ 'svg' => 'image/svg+xml' ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve where .zip files were seen as `application/zip` by PHP but detected as `application/x-zip-compressed`.

My workaround was to add this new value with an invented key

```
'xzip' => '`application/x-zip-compressed';
```

See https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23510

See also two WordPress TRACs:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40175
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46775