# How to upload .tex files in wordpress?

Tags: uploads, wp-filesystem

I am trying to upload tex files in my wordpress site. The methods I have tried and failed or the following. First of all the error I got is,

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

### Tried Methods:

- Method 1:

Added the below line in `wp-config.php`

> define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);

Which did not work.

- Method 2

Added the following codes which allows mime types in functions.php

```
// Adding Mime types 
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
  $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';     // Adding .svg extension
  $mime_types['json'] = 'application/json'; // Adding .json extension
  $mime_types['tex'] = 'application/octet-stream'; // Adding .tex extension   
  return $mime_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types');
```

which again did not help. I remember that only once the file got uploaded in local copy of the website which I dont know how?

- Method 3

Added the plugin WP Add Mime Types, thinking that I can try adding the mime type. But It already shows me that 'appliations/x-tex' is already added from the method 2.

[image]

None of the above method helped me to upload the .tex files. Note that pdf files are getting uploaded without any issue.

PS: I am using a form to upload files. You may check [here](https://carams.in/abstract-submission-portal/) . 
Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323750/how-to-assign-multiple-file-mime-types-to-extension/323757#323757)  can help

Answer (score 0):

Mime Type are not correct.

application/x-tex

[image]

Complete detail MimeType Source : https://www.lifewire.com/mime-types-by-content-type-3469108

Comment: Actually this did not work for me in the initial stage itself. Since, my file type shown that 'application/octet-stream', I have changed the tex file mime type to   'application/octet-stream'