# Upload restrictions - upload_mimes - filter: Adding multiple MIMEs for a single extension and adding multiple extensions for a single MIME type?

Tags: filters, uploads, media-library, videos

Trying to add certain allowed MIME types to the upload filter - currently my custom function looks like this:

```
// allow SVG and video mime types for upload
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
    $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['webm'] = 'video/webm';
    $mimes['mp4']  = ['video/mp4','video/mpeg'];
    $mimes['ogg']  = 'video/ogg';
    $mimes['ogv']  = 'video/ogg';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );
```

Uploading videos with ogg/ogv format seems to work well, but MP4 is failing. It seems like an array of different MIME types is not the solution. How should I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MikeNGarret's answer pointed me to the interesting function `wp_get_mime_types()`.  Within this function you can look up how to correctly add MIME types to the `upload_mimes` filter (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L2707).

The correct answer therefore is:

```
// allow SVG and video mime types for upload
function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
    $mimes['svg']      = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['webm']     = 'video/webm';
    $mimes['mp4|m4v']  = 'video/mp4';
    $mimes['mpeg|mpg|mpe']  = 'video/mpeg';
    $mimes['ogv']      = 'video/ogg';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );
```

For registering an unknown MIME type you should therefore use the `mime_types` filter, for the upload (independently) you have to add it to the list of allowed upload mimes.

Comment: Note that this answers half the question - you can add multiple extensions to a single mime-type. But how can you do the other half, add multiple mime-types to a single extension? eg a .DXF file can legitimately be `text/plain` or `applications/octet-stream` as both text and binary versions exist.

Comment: @benz001 Never have needed this. Have you tried an array?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work, also tried comma-separated mimes as per some other article - what I had to do was wrap around the check and if it failed loop through an array of alternate mime types retrying the check each time as per https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323750/how-to-assign-multiple-file-mime-types-to-extension/346169#346169
This seems like a core bug that there is no filter/mechanism to support this - for us it killed our file upload gravity form.

Comment: @benz001 Ok thats good to know. You should do a feature request in: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ - because this is really something WordPress should be capable of.

Answer (score 2):

This filter only accepts strings for mime types. It also [already has support for webm, mp4, mpeg, ogv, and ogg](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L2707).

I think you can remove everything except the line for SVGs.

A word of warning, WordPress doesn't support SVG upload by default because it's a security concern. Be careful about enabling this. At the least, use something like the [Safe SVG plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/) to help mitigate the risk.

Comment: Not all files/extensions in this list are allowed within the upload_mime's filter (at least not in the installation I have tested it). Anyway thank you very much for the list (+1), now I know ho to do it.