# Allow EPS file upload - two EPS files have different MIME types

Tags: filters, uploads

I got this error message when trying to upload EPS-files to my WordPress Media Library:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons

So I added this snippet to my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', function ( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types[ 'eps' ] = 'application/postscript';

    return $mime_types;
} );
```

After that I can upload several different EPS files locally on my development machine (Windows 10, PHP 7.0.19). However, on the remote server (CentOS, PHP 7.2.15), I still get the error message for *certain* EPS files.

After some debugging and troubleshooting I realized that the PHP versions differed so I downgraded PHP to version 7.0.33 on the remote server and suddenly I could upload all EPS files.

Any ideas regarding what the problem might be? Has something changed between PHP 7.0 and 7.2 that would make the `upload_mimes` filter fail?

WordPress is the latest version, 5.0.3.

Comment: I guess `finfo_file()` is working differently between PHP versions here? Hopefully [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/323757/26350) recent answer can help or the answers given [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/321804/26350)?.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the problem is only with certain EPS files which are identified as "image/x-eps" instead of the more common "application/postscript" by the `finfo_file()` function in more recent versions of PHP (somewhere between 7.0.33 and 7.2.15).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In recent versions of WordPress ([5.0.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/12/13/backwards-compatibility-breaks-in-5-0-1/) or higher) file upload security has been tightened by actually checking the content of an uploaded file using the PHP function [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to determine if the file extension matches the MIME type. This has proven problematic since files with the same file type and extension may yield different MIME types.

In my case one EPS file (let's call it `one.eps`) was detected as "application/postscript" while another file (let's call it `two.eps`) as "image/x-eps" or "application/octet-stream" depending on which PHP version the server was running.

After adding the below PHP snippet I was consistently able to upload file `one.eps` to the WordPress Media Library no matter what version of PHP I was using. But the file `two.eps` could not be uploaded if the server was running PHP 7.2 or higher.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', function ( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types[ 'eps' ] = 'application/postscript';
    return $mime_types;
} );
```

I'm by no means an expert on the EPS file format but I think it's safe to assume that different variations on the format exists. Opening the two files in different applications and checking the content strengthens this belief:

Opening the files in a text editor:

- `one.eps` Has an ASCII/human readable file header
- `two.eps` Appears binary

Format according to GIMP:

- `one.eps` application/postscript
- `two.eps` image/epsf

Format according to finfo_file() on PHP 7.0.10:

- `one.eps` application/postscript
- `two.eps` application/octet-stream

Format according to finfo_file() on PHP 7.3.2:

- `one.eps` application/postscript
- `two.eps` image/x-eps

In the WordPress core file `wp-includes/functions.php`, function `wp_check_filetype_and_ext()` you will find the following:

```
// fileinfo often misidentifies obscure files as one of these types
$nonspecific_types = array(
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/encrypted',
    'application/CDFV2-encrypted',
    'application/zip',
);
```

Further down in the function there is a hard-coded exception to allow these MIME types under certain circumstances. This is what made it possible to upload `two.eps` on earlier PHP versions, since `finfo_file()` reported "application/octet-stream" as its MIME type and this is one of the hard-coded exceptions.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no mechanism in WordPress to allow the same extension to be mapped to different MIME types, which (to me) would be the most obvious solution. Something along the lines of:

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', function ( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types[ 'eps' ] = array('application/postscript', 'image/x-eps');
    return $mime_types;
} );
```

However, the user @birgire [posted a workaround as an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323750/how-to-assign-multiple-file-mime-types-to-extension/323757#323757) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution for uploading eps or ai files in wordpress

```
function custom_wp_check_filetype_and_ext($filetype_and_ext, $file, $filename) {
   if(!$filetype_and_ext['ext'] || !$filetype_and_ext['type'] || !$filetype_and_ext['proper_filename']) {
        $extension = pathinfo($filename)['extension'];
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($file);
        $allowed_ext = array(
            'eps' => array('application/postscript', 'image/x-eps'),
            'ai' => array('application/postscript'),
        );
        if($allowed_ext[$extension]) {
            if(in_array($mime_type, $allowed_ext[$extension])) {
                $filetype_and_ext['ext'] = $extension;
                $filetype_and_ext['type'] = $mime_type;
                $filetype_and_ext['proper_filename'] = $filename;
            }
        }
    }
    return $filetype_and_ext;
}

/** **/
add_filter('wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'custom_wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 5, 5);
```